# Visual Studio static library : NuGet package not found when using in another project

Tags: c++, static-libraries, glfw

I'm building a static library using Visual Studio, which involves installing `nupengl` and `glm`. Then I linked it to a test project via this method :

- Project Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Additional include library (I entered the directory which contains my header files from the library)
- Project Properties -> Linker -> Input (I entered the directory which contains the .lib file for the library)
- I added the header files in the library to my test project

But when I run the test program, it produces things like :

- `GLFW/glfw3 not found`

How can I use the installed `NuGet` package for the library when calling the library from another project ? Any help would be highly appreciated